# Reference static const variables declared in namespace

Tags: doxygen

I am fleshing out the doxygen documentation for my modules and came across a strange problem. When referencing variables located in a namespace autolinking does not work. Here is a snippet:

```
namespace isa {

const double H_max= 10000; //!< @brief Maximum altitude in meters.

//! @brief Calculate air densitity at altitude \a H.
//! @throw argument_exception when \a H exceeds ::H_max.
double rho(double H);

} // namespace isa
```

I would expect doxygen to put a link to H_max at the exception description of function rho(double) to direct the reader to the constant. But it only does if I leave away the namespace, otherwise autolinking does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I leave away the namespace"? Do you remove the double colon prefix in `::H_max`?

Comment: @Antonio: when I remove "namespace isa {" and the respective closing brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the problem here is not a doxygen wrong behavior, but a misunderstanding on how the global namespace prefix `::` works.

`::H_max` identifies a symbol defined in the global namespace, that is, out of any namespace. I'm afraid - correct me if I'm wrong - that you where expecting it to behave as the parent directory `..` identifier.

When doxygen processes the code snippet you provided, it doesn't link `::H_max` in the exception description because it cannot find a `H_max` variable in the global namespace. If you remove the double colon prefix, it should provide a link to `isa::H_max`.

Comment: things magically work now even with the sample provided... thanks anyway for clarifying on the :: operator.