# Doxygen for property declared in a different file using?

Tags: objective-c, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation, mogenerator

I use [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) to generate [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) classes. Mogenerator produces machine classes and human classes. A developer is not supposed to modify machine generated classes, since these are generated each time mogenerator is called. Human classes can, however, be modified as the developer pleases.

Machine classes contain the declaration of every property of the Core Data entity. In Doxygen, how does one document a property defined in file A from file B?

**EDIT: Added example to illustrate the question**

*Example:*

Ultimately, the goal here to have something similar to the example below.

**FileA.h (can not be modified)**

```
@interface FileA : NSObject
{
   NSString* myProperty;
}
@end
```

**FileB.h**

```
#include "FileA.h"

@interface FileB : FileA
{
   /**
    * @property myProperty
    *
    * This is the documentation of "myProperty" 
    * defined in FileA but documented in FileB
    */
}
@end
```

**Tried (documentation block inside the @interface FileB @end bock):**

*@property myProperty* - Doxygen does not associated the documentation to the property.

*\property myProperty* - Doxygen does not associated the documentation to the property.

*@property FileA::myProperty* - Doxygen does not associated the documentation to the property and generates; warning: no uniquely matching class member found for FileB::myProperty

*\property FileA::myProperty* - Idem

**Solution**

**FileB.h**

```
#include "FileA.h"

   /**
    * @property FileA::myProperty
    *
    * This is the documentation of "myProperty" 
    * defined in FileA but documented in FileB
    *
    * Documentation block MUST BE outside FileB class
    *
    */

@interface FileB : FileA
{
}
@end
```

Comment: Why don't you try `\property FileA::myProperty` and let us know what happens?

Comment: Your use of `@interface FileB : FileA` doesn't match the documentation for the [`\interface`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmdinterface) command. Also, you state in your solution that "Documentation block MUST BE outside FileB class". This shouldn't be the case - this suggests something else isn't working as expected.

Comment: Also, note that you can use `@` or \ as the prefix for Doxygen commands, so `\property` and `@property` are the same thing, there is no need to differentiate between them. When you used `@property FileA::myProperty` you say you got the warning "no uniquely matching class member found for FileB::myProperty". Surely this should be `FileA::myProperty`?

Comment: @Chris: "Documentation block MUST BE outside FileB class". This shouldn't be the case - this suggests something else isn't working as expected. Any idea ?

Comment: @Chris: I knew about @ or \ as the prefix for Doxygen commands but wanted to make sure one did not have some kind of undocumented/weird behaviour.

Comment: In response to your first comment: from your source snippet I'm not sure why. I still don't think the notation `FileB : FileA` is correct. If you run Doxygen on the two example files given in my answer does it work as expected?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6677/discussion-between-david-andreoletti-and-chris)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unclear (to me) whether you want `FileA` to be documented, but you can't insert the documentation into `FileA.h`, or if you want `FileA` to be undocumented, but have its members appear in the (documented) derived class `FileB`.

If its the former, you can provide documentation for class `FileA` in `FileB.h`, this would appear as something like:

```
/**
 * @class FileA
 * Documentation for FileA
 *
 * @var FileA::myProperty
 * Documentation for myProperty
 */

/**
 * Documentation for FileB
 */
@interface FileB : FileA
{
}

@end
```

This will cause classes `FileA` and `FileB` to appear in the generated docs, with `myProperty` documented as a member of `FileA`.

If its the latter, you could declare `myProperty` as a member of `FileB`, but use a preprocessor guard to only include the declaration when generating your documentation, something like:

```
/**
 * document FileB
 */
@interface FileB : FileA
{
#ifdef DOXYGEN
    /**
     * This is the documentation of "myProperty" 
     * defined in FileA but documented in FileB
     */
    NSString* myProperty;
#endif
}

@end
```

This will cause `FileB` to be documented as if `myProperty` was one of its members. Be aware that if the declaration of `myProperty` changes in `FileA`, you'll have to manually update `FileB`'s declaration to reflect those changes.

Comment: Ideal solution would be the second option: Have FileA undocumented BUT have its members/accessors appear in the (documented) derived class FileB.

This is better from a developer's point of view who reads the documentation about FileB. Ideally, FileA does not exist in the developer's mind (as well as in the documentation)

Comment: I finally went for the former proposed solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference an achor (e.g. files, namespaces, classes, functions, variables, enums etc) using Doxygen's [`ref`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdref) command using, for example

```
\ref variable_name
```

If the variable you want to document is not in the local namespace or scope, you can prefix the variable name with `namespace::`, where `namespace` is the scope or class where the variable you are referring to is defined. For example, consider the following two files (modified from examples in the Doxygen manual):

**File 1**:

```
///  A test class.
/**
  A more elaborate class description.
*/
class Test
{
  public:

  /// An enum.
  /** More detailed enum description. */
  enum TEnum {
               TVal1, ///< Enum value TVal1.
               TVal2, ///< Enum value TVal2.
               TVal3  ///< Enum value TVal3.
             }
      /// Enum pointer.
      /** Details. */
      *enumPtr,
      /// Enum variable.
      /** Details. */
      enumVar;

  /// A constructor.
  /**
    A more elaborate description of the constructor.
  */
  Test();
};
```

**File 2**:

```
//  Another test class.
/**
  This class depends on the variable \ref Test::TEnum, defined in another file.
  It doesn't, actually, but I've said it does.
*/
class AnotherTest
{
  public:

  /// A constructor
  AnotherTest();

};
```

Here `TEnum` is defined in the class `Test` in the first file. So in the second file, we prefix the variable name with the class in which it is defined, i.e. `Test::TEnum`.

See the accepted answer to the question [Reference static const variables declared in namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922679/reference-static-const-variables-declared-in-namespace) for more information on the global namespace prefix `::`.